# Webpack will constantly "Compiling successfully" and "Compiling" after touching a file

Tags: reactjs, webpack, electron

[image]

```js
import path from 'path';
import fs from 'fs';
import webpack from 'webpack';
import chalk from 'chalk';
import { merge } from 'webpack-merge';
import { spawn, execSync } from 'child_process';
import baseConfig from './webpack.config.base';
import CheckNodeEnv from '../scripts/CheckNodeEnv';
import ReactRefreshWebpackPlugin from '@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin';

// When an ESLint server is running, we can't set the NODE_ENV so we'll check if it's
// at the dev webpack config is not accidentally run in a production environment
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  CheckNodeEnv('development');
}

const port = process.env.PORT || 1212;
const publicPath = `http://localhost:${port}/dist`;
const dllDir = path.join(__dirname, '../dll');
const manifest = path.resolve(dllDir, 'renderer.json');
const requiredByDLLConfig = module.parent.filename.includes(
  'webpack.config.renderer.dev.dll'
);

/**
 * Warn if the DLL is not built
 */
if (!requiredByDLLConfig && !(fs.existsSync(dllDir) && fs.existsSync(manifest))) {
  console.log(
    chalk.black.bgYellow.bold(
      'The DLL files are missing. Sit back while we build them for you with "yarn build-dll"'
    )
  );
  execSync('yarn build-dll');
}

export default merge(baseConfig, {
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',

  mode: 'development',

  target: 'electron-renderer',

  entry: [
    'core-js',
    'regenerator-runtime/runtime',
    require.resolve('../../src/renderer/index.tsx'),
  ],

  output: {
    publicPath: `http://localhost:${port}/dist/`,
    filename: 'renderer.dev.js',
  },

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.[jt]sx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: require.resolve('babel-loader'),
            options: {
              plugins: [
                require.resolve('react-refresh/babel'),
              ].filter(Boolean),
            },
          },
          
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.global\.css$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'style-loader',
          },
          {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: {
              sourceMap: true,
            },
          },
          {
            loader: 'postcss-loader',
            options: {
              postcssOptions: {
                plugins: [require('tailwindcss'), require('autoprefixer')],
                },
            }
          }
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /^((?!\.global).)*\.css$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'style-loader',
          },
          {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: {
              modules: {
                localIdentName: '[name]__[local]__[hash:base64:5]',
              },
              sourceMap: true,
              importLoaders: 1,
            },
          },
          {
            loader: 'postcss-loader',
            options: {
              postcssOptions: {
                plugins: [require('tailwindcss'), require('autoprefixer')],
                },
            }
          }
        ],
      },
      // SASS support - compile all .global.scss files and pipe it to style.css
      {
        test: /\.global\.(scss|sass)$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'style-loader',
          },
          {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: {
              sourceMap: true,
            },
          },
          {
            loader: 'sass-loader',
          },
        ],
      },
      // SASS support - compile all other .scss files and pipe it to style.css
      {
        test: /^((?!\.global).)*\.(scss|sass)$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'style-loader',
          },
          {
            loader: '@teamsupercell/typings-for-css-modules-loader',
          },
          {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: {
              modules: {
                localIdentName: '[name]__[local]__[hash:base64:5]',
              },
              sourceMap: true,
              importLoaders: 1,
            },
          },
          {
            loader: 'sass-loader',
          },
        ],
      },
      // WOFF Font
      {
        test: /\.woff(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
        use: {
          loader: 'url-loader',
          options: {
            limit: 10000,
            mimetype: 'application/font-woff',
          },
        },
      },
      // WOFF2 Font
      {
        test: /\.woff2(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
        use: {
          loader: 'url-loader',
          options: {
            limit: 10000,
            mimetype: 'application/font-woff',
          },
        },
      },
      // OTF Font
      {
        test: /\.otf(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
        use: {
          loader: 'url-loader',
          options: {
            limit: 10000,
            mimetype: 'font/otf',
          },
        },
      },
      // TTF Font
      {
        test: /\.ttf(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
        use: {
          loader: 'url-loader',
          options: {
            limit: 10000,
            mimetype: 'application/octet-stream',
          },
        },
      },
      // EOT Font
      {
        test: /\.eot(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
        use: 'file-loader',
      },
      // SVG Font
      {
        test: /\.svg(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
        use: {
          loader: 'url-loader',
          options: {
            limit: 10000,
            mimetype: 'image/svg+xml',
          },
        },
      },
      // Common Image Formats
      {
        test: /\.(?:ico|gif|png|jpg|jpeg|webp)$/,
        use: 'url-loader',
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [

    requiredByDLLConfig
      ? null
      : new webpack.DllReferencePlugin({
          context: path.join(__dirname, '../dll'),
          manifest: require(manifest),
          sourceType: 'var',
        }),

    new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin(),

    /**
     * Create global constants which can be configured at compile time.
     *
     * Useful for allowing different behaviour between development builds and
     * release builds
     *
     * NODE_ENV should be production so that modules do not perform certain
     * development checks
     *
     * By default, use 'development' as NODE_ENV. This can be overriden with
     * 'staging', for example, by changing the ENV variables in the npm scripts
     */
    new webpack.EnvironmentPlugin({
      NODE_ENV: 'development',
    }),

    new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
      debug: true,
    }),

    new ReactRefreshWebpackPlugin(),
  ],

  node: {
    __dirname: false,
    __filename: false,
  },

  devServer: {
    disableHostCheck: true,
    port,
    publicPath,
    compress: true,
    noInfo: false,
    stats: 'errors-only',
    inline: true,
    lazy: false,
    hot: true,
    headers: { 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' },
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    watchOptions: {
      aggregateTimeout: 300,
      ignored: /node_modules/,
      poll: 100,
    },
    historyApiFallback: {
      verbose: true,
      disableDotRule: false,
    },
    before() {
      console.log('Starting Main Process...');
        spawn('npm', ['run', 'start:main'], {
          shell: true,
          env: process.env,
          stdio: 'inherit',
        })
          .on('close', (code) => process.exit(code))
          .on('error', (spawnError) => console.error(spawnError));
    },
  },
});
```

I use the https://github.com/electron-react-boilerplate/electron-react-boilerplate as the template to do a electron application. After introducing tailwind css and react router, my web devserver will constantly compile like image after touching a file. Does any one has the issue and give me a help? Sorry about too many js code in webpack configuration js, but I think lots of part can be skpied.

Comment: Not sure I understand--if a file is changed it'll recompile; that's the point of watching the files. Are you saying it's compiling even if no file has changed?

Comment: @DaveNewton yes.  what I need to clarify is that one-time compiling and compiled successfully is acceptable and reasonable while now it's non-stop compiling and compiled successfully.

Comment: @truejasonxiefans did you resolve this? i'm facing the same issue

Comment: @OumaimaAbouElMawahib I have fixed but I don't clear know why. I doubt mostly caused by wrong route visit